# Как отобразить стили на локальном сервере?

Tags: php, opencart3.x

При переносе сайта, написанный на Опенкарте, на локальный сервер не отображаются стилисайт отображается без стилей.Как их правильно подключить чтобы и на локальном заработали?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте корректность путей до каталогов сайта в конфигах CMS - config.php

+ нужно смотреть в консоль браузера, чтобы увидеть точные причины, из-за которых стили недоступны.

Comment: закоментил строку <base href="{{ base }}" />  и заработало.Но  так и не понял где прописывается base,тот что в скобках.Как я понимаю это  через шаблонизатор Twig создается и по идее дольжен быть в контроллере, но пока не нашел:(

Comment: Если локальный сервер unix-овый, то можно попробовать  `grep -ir base /путь до корневой директории сайта/`

Comment: использую Винду:)